# How to create a PDF/E file with Video for long-term archiving system?

Tags: pdf, pdfa

I am trying to create a PDF/A file for long-term archiving system. My PDF file has a Video. I check in [Wikipedia PDF/A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A) doesn't accept video content. [PDF/X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/X) is for graphics exchange and last, [PDF/E](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/E) is for the dynamic content like videos. I am trying with Acrobat Pro to create a PDF/E file, but at the end i am getting a failure message that Acrobat can not create the PDF/E file. There is this Preflight inside Acrobat Pro but it has the same failure again during the convert process. Is there any other solution to create a PDF/E file with video inside, or even is it possible to create a long-term archiving PDF with a video inside?

Comment: PDF/E is actually for engineering mostly (hence the "E") but it does indeed allow interactive content as well. What is the warning (or what are the warnings) that Preflight gives you? Alternatively, can you supply a sample file so that I can try to get it through callas pdfToolbox (which has the same technology as Preflight).

Comment: The first warning from Preflight is: `The document has been saved, however, it could not be converted according to the 
selected standard profile: Convert to PDF/E. Please use Preflight with the profile
"Convert to PDF/E" in order to identify those properties of the document
which prevent it from being compliant to this profile.` 
After i am trying to convert it to PDF/E with Preflight then i am getting these errors: (I just createad all sample files and reports):  [All sample files](http://www.uni-ak.ac.at/p0008946/files/)
- I guess there is a RGB and CMYK problem, but i am not so sure.

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche any suggestions? Can u download my sample files?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no - there is currently no archival standard for PDFs with embedded video. However, there is little evidence that standard PDF is going to go obsolete any time soon, so I think the best strategy may be simply to wait for the standards to catch up.

If you're seeking a little more reassurance, you could check if other PDF renderers support your files. If one or more of the open source implementations have no problem with it, then there's very little reason to suppose the content is at risk.

If you really want to protect against problems with PDF, you could diversify somewhat and make a HTML+MP4 version of the same content. That would ensure that even if the PDF strategy fails, there's something else to fall back on. Having some or all of the content of one item available in alternate formats also makes any future format conversions easier to validate.

Comment: i was contacting the PDF/A organisation and they wrote in their forum that is for now not possible. Here is the [link to their forum](http://www.pdfa.org/discussion-forum/pdf-en/how-to-create-a-pdfe-file-with-video-for-long-term-archiving-system/)